# Register Spring filter from BeanDefinitionParser

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am creating a custom namespace for use in the Spring XML configuration. I already implemented a `NamespaceHandler` and `BeanDefinitionParser`. So, now I can just put `<myns:some-awesome-feature />` into my Spring configuration and it creates the required beans automatically.

In addition to creating some normal Spring beans I would also like to have this annotation register a `OncePerRequestFilter` to extract some information off of a request for my code to be able to utilize. Is there a way to register a filter programmatically using the two classes I have available when implementing a custom XML tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible without touching `web.xml` or [`WebApplicationInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html), respectively.
But you can create an extendable solution that allows modifications in future  without hassle.

Spring Security's `<http pattern='...' security="..."/>` automatically creates and registers a series of chained filter beans for you. All you have to do is to
register [`DelegatingFilterProxy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) in you `web.xml` and reference `springSecurityFilterChain`.

You can create a similar solution where you are defining e.g. `<myns:awesome-http pattern='...' />` which instantiates `OncePerRequestFilter`. In `web.xml` you are declaring a `DelegatingFilterProxy` which references your `awesomeFilterChain`. In a future version you can add more filter to your chain without touching the configuration.

I have never implemented such a feature but I'm quite confident that it is possible.

As a starting point take a look at the source of [`HttpConfigurationBuilder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.0.0.M2/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/http/HttpConfigurationBuilder.java) and [`HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.0.0.M2/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/http/HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java) to see how Spring Security implemented `<http .../>`.

Comment: I was kind of afraid the answer would be "you can't really do it". Using the `DelegatingFilterProxy` kind of defeats the purpose of what I was hoping to do. I am writing something that is a library to be used in multiple applications. So, I was hoping the custom spring tag would be able to do all of the setup needed, including registering a filter.

Comment: I saw that `javax.servlet.ServletContext` had some methods for adding filters, but they seem to not actually work at the point that I would be calling them.

Comment: You can't use `javax.servlet.ServletContext` for that purpose. `ServletContext::addFilter` is available only during initialization, so right before your library code really kicks in. Spring Security resorts to `DelegatingFilterProxy` because there is no other way. Of course, you can use `@WebFilter` in a servlet 3.0 container. But you can't support servlet 2.x spec anymore, you lose dependency injection and you'll need to resort to the `web.xml` again when requiring a specific order of your filters.

Comment: Yeah, I figured `addFilter` was a longshot. It was pretty quick to try and find out it didn't work. Thanks for the input. For now I've decided there isn't a way to do exactly what I was hoping.